# String equation for simple to complex equations

Tags: java, string, arraylist, equation, parentheses

I'm trying to write a program that solves any equation (from simple to complex) in the form of a string by using an Arraylist to break down the equation into seperate parts. It checks for parentheses first, then goes into the deepest set of parentheses it can find, and solves the set of operations inside, starting with the stronger operators, then moves on. It continues checking until there are no more parentheses, then it does what's left, starting with the stronger operators. The number left over in the arraylist is the answer. But I'm having trouble. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringEquation
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "80+5+3*(11%(3*2)-(5+1)+6)-(10+10)+(2*2)*5";

        ArrayList<String> equation = new ArrayList<>();

        String ns = "";

        String b;

        int nsi;

        int si;

        int res = 0;

        boolean hasParen = false;

        for(int c=0; c<s.length(); c++)
        {
             b = s.substring(c,c+1);
             if("0".equals(b)||"1".equals(b)||"2".equals(b)||"3".equals(b)||"4".equals(b)||"5".equals(b)||"6".equals(b)||"7".equals(b)||"8".equals(b)||"9".equals(b))
             {
                 ns += b;
                 if(c==s.length()-1)
                 {
                     nsi = Integer.parseInt(ns);
                     equation.add(Integer.toString(nsi));
                 }
             }
             else if(("+".equals(b)||"-".equals(b)||"*".equals(b)||"/".equals(b)||"%".equals(b))&&!"".equals(ns))
             {
                nsi = Integer.parseInt(ns);
                equation.add(Integer.toString(nsi));
                equation.add(b);
                ns = "";
             }
             else if("(".equals(b))
             {
                 equation.add(b);
             }
             else if (")".equals(b))
             {
                nsi = Integer.parseInt(ns);
                equation.add(Integer.toString(nsi));
                equation.add(b);
                ns = "";
             }
             else if("+".equals(b)||"-".equals(b)||"*".equals(b)||"/".equals(b)||"%".equals(b))
             {
                 equation.add(b);
             }
        }

        while(true) //checks for parentheses
        {
            for(int d=0; d<equation.size(); d++)
            {
                if("(".equals(equation.get(d)))
                {
                    hasParen = true;
                }

                if(hasParen==true)
                {
                    while(!")".equals(equation.get(d)))
                    {
                        d++;
                    }
                    while(!"(".equals(equation.get(d)))
                    {
                        d--;
                    }
                    d++;

                    while(!")".equals(equation.get(d+1)))
                    {
                        if("-".equals(equation.get(d))) //checks to see if the String number on the Arraylist is negative
                        {
                            equation.remove(d);
                            si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d));
                            si *= -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d));
                        }

                        switch(equation.get(d+1))
                        {
                            case "*": si *= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d+2)); 
                            equation.set(d, Integer.toString(si));
                            equation.remove(d+1);
                            equation.remove(d+2);
                                break;
                            case "/": si /= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d+2));
                            equation.set(d, Integer.toString(si));
                            equation.remove(d+1);
                            equation.remove(d+2);
                                break;
                            case "%": si %= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d+2));
                            equation.set(d, Integer.toString(si));
                            equation.remove(d+1);
                            equation.remove(d+2);
                                break;
                            default: d+=2;
                        }
                    }

                    while(!"(".equals(equation.get(d)))
                    {
                        d--;
                    }
                    d++;

                    while(!")".equals(equation.get(d+1)))
                    {
                        if("-".equals(equation.get(d))) //checks to see if the String number on the Arraylist is negative
                        {
                            equation.remove(d);
                            si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d));
                            si *= -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d));
                        }

                        switch(equation.get(d+1))
                        {
                            case "+": si += Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d+2)); 
                            equation.set(d, Integer.toString(si));
                            equation.remove(d+1);
                            equation.remove(d+2);
                                break;
                            case "-": si -= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(d+2));
                            equation.set(d, Integer.toString(si));
                            equation.remove(d+1);
                            equation.remove(d+2);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    if("(".equals(equation.get(d-1))&&")".equals(equation.get(d+1)))
                    {
                        equation.remove(d-1);
                        equation.remove(d+1);
                    }

                    hasParen = false;

                    d = 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        for(int e=0; e<equation.size(); e+=2) //does all multiplication, division and modulus first
        {
            if("-".equals(equation.get(e))) //checks to see if the String number on the Arraylist is negative
            {
                equation.remove(e);
                si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(e));
                si *= -1;
            }
            else
            {
                si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(e));
            }

            switch(equation.get(e+1))
            {
                case "*": si *= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(e+2)); 
                equation.set(e, Integer.toString(si));
                equation.remove(e+1);
                equation.remove(e+2);
                    break;
                case "/": si /= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(e+2));
                equation.set(e, Integer.toString(si));
                equation.remove(e+1);
                equation.remove(e+2);
                    break;
                case "%": si %= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(e+2));
                equation.set(e, Integer.toString(si));
                equation.remove(e+1);
                equation.remove(e+2);
                    break;
                default: e+=2;
            }
        }

        for(int f=0; f<equation.size(); f+=2) //does the rest (addition and subtraction)
        {
            if("-".equals(equation.get(f))) //checks to see if the String number on the Arraylist is negative
            {
                equation.remove(f);
                si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(f));
                si *= -1;
            }
            else
            {
                si = Integer.parseInt(equation.get(f));
            }

            switch(equation.get(f+1))
            {
                case "+": si += Integer.parseInt(equation.get(f+2)); 
                equation.set(f, Integer.toString(si));
                equation.remove(f+1);
                equation.remove(f+2);
                    break;
                case "-": si -= Integer.parseInt(equation.get(f+2));
                equation.set(f, Integer.toString(si));
                equation.remove(f+1);
                equation.remove(f+2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(equation.get(0)); //Arraylist should only have the answer of the string equation by this point.

        //The part below was to see if lines 25-59 had obtained the whole equation in seperate parts within the arraylist.

//        for(int i=0; i<equation.size(); i++)
//        {
//            System.out.print(equation.get(i));
//        }
//        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

When I run this, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "("
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at stringequationfull.StringEquationFull.main(StringEquationFull.java:87)
Java Result: 1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

> Throws: **NumberFormatException** - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable integer.

The error message you're getting is very informative.

You're trying to parse `"("`, which is **not** a parsable integer.

Using a debugger will solve this for you in less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a parsing/lexing framework for this, and then implement the equation solver on top of the parse tree.

Here's a starting point: [How to write LALR parser for some grammar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401132/how-to-write-lalr-parser-for-some-grammar-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are trying to parse "(" as an Integer.

But this is not your main problem.

The main issue is that you have a huge gigantic hunk of code which is unnecessarily hard to reason about.

You need to convert the string into a tree like structure instead of an array list which would allow you to do the calculations in a much easier and bug free way.

Since your problem is simple I would not recommend using a parser generator for this task. ( takes too long imho ). However you will still need to design the data structure to suit your requirements.

There are a bunch of parsers for mathematical equations that you can examine to get an inspiration from.

In general you will have something like:

```
Class Statement{}

class AddStatement extends Statement{
    Statement lhs;
    Statement rhs;
}

Class constant extends Statement{
    int value;
}
```

you will need to make classes for all the operations you support and then  recursively parse the input into this structure. If done properly, evaluation becomes simple.

I am not going into detail because there are enough resources available online to use for guidance.

If you wish you can continue with your code above but I would recommend you somehow figure out how to split it into smaller chunks which are easier to debug and good luck

Comment: P.S this is so much easier in functional languages like haskell